# Sign in activity to main activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a main activity with some buttons on it that leads to other activities but I have decided to authenticate the user to make them sign in before they can start using the app. How would I go from the sign in activity to the main activity? Do I just use an intent to the main activity?

Answer (score 3):

In my project , I used this in MainActivity:

```
    if (!SessionManager.getInstance().hasSignIn())
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class));
```

and after you do this, user can still finish the SignInActivity , and back to MainActivity , so if you don't want your users go into MainActivity before they sign in ,you need to make sure SignInActivity has override the onKeyDown event

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in psedocode terms:

```
if(authenication.wasSuccessful){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, mainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The "main activity" is just an activity like all the others. You can start it from the "authentication activity" in exactly the same way that you already start the other activities from the "main activity".

Be sure to update AndroidManifest.xml so that the "authentication activity" is the one that the Launcher starts and not the "main activity".